# How to run privileged Docker container for using systemctl

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, init, systemctl

I am new to Docker and I am trying to use `systemctl` to restart a service. It constantly fails and `Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted`. I understand that in order to bypass this I need to run a privileged docker container, however, this still does not produce my desired results.

Please see below for the steps I took and the files involved:

#### Docker command result

```
docker run --privileged testapp /sbin/init
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:14.0.1

# Copies required files to the Linux container
COPY ./out/production/TestingApp/ /App
COPY test.sh /App
COPY expressvpn-2.5.1.1-1.x86_64.rpm /App

WORKDIR /App

RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install sudo && yum -y install expect && yum -y install systemd
RUN yum -y install expressvpn-2.5.1.1-1.x86_64.rpm

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "Main"]
```

#### test.sh

In my Main.java this shell script file is executed and the output is printed out to the console.

```
sudo systemctl start expressvpn.service
expressvpn status
```

Comment: Not related to SO! SO is for programming while your question is about using/installing/configuring software.

Comment: how?... the error is about operation not permitted using `systemctl` whether it is expressvpn or google or http, I still get that error. Its just that in example I am trying to use systemctl to start an expressvpn service

Answer (score -3):

try

```
docker run -u 0 testapp /sbin/init
```